# Make some calls asynchronously and return from Spring Controller immediately

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot, and I have a POST endpoint which needs to do various things such as persist an object to the database, and then also call 3-4 other services.  However, I'd like to return a response shortly after the database call is persisted and then call the other services on another thread, asynchronously?  The call to the other 3-4 services are okay to be eventually consistent (e.g. call to keen.io analytics service).  How is this easily doable in Spring Boot?

Comment: so kick the tasks off in another thread.

Comment: And it'd be alright if the controller returns?

Comment: you will not know if the un-finished tasks complete successfully or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you do not even need spring for this job. You could use [java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#runAsync](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) to run sth async on a different thread.

Also you could use the spring [async support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled). Just annotate a spring bean method (in your case returning void) with `@Async`. And do not forget to enable async support by annotating a configuration class with [@EnableAsync](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-enable-annotation-support).

Comment: Agree with Mathias, Spring Async looks the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a thread running that is monitoring a queue to determine when to execute some work. When a request has completed its immediate task then it would add information to the queue so that the monitoring thread can understand that it needs to do some work. You could have a pool of threads monitoring the queue to improve performance. This is a fairly standard pattern for event based programming which offers ability to have actions run async.